# mysql Update table after querying from it

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table filled with first and last names. I have two other columns that I am trying to update. These two columns has the number of people that have the same first names and same last names. For example,

```
first   last   samef   samel

John    Smith   1      2  
John    Adams   1      1  
Mary    Kate    0      0  
Kate    Adams   2      1  
Kate    Smith   2      2   
Kate    Smith   2      2  
Alice   Mirth   0      0
```

So far I can only come up with these two queries, but of course they are not correct. They return the total count for each name when I need the total count - 1. Plus, the results are shown on separate tables.
I was wondering if I should use a stored procedure where I use variables to store the count for samef and samel. And then insert it into the names table, but I don't know the correct syntax for this.

```
SELECT first, last,
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names WHERE first = table1.first) AS samef 
FROM names AS table1

SELECT first, last,
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names WHERE last = table2.last) AS samel 
FROM names AS table2
```

I am new to mySQL so please provide explanations.

Comment: Why store this information?

Comment: It's a exercise from a textbook for a section about how updates cannot be done when reading from the table.

Comment: Well, in practice, you wouldn't normally store data that can be derived from other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Strawberry mentioned, do not store information that can be derived. Databases are great at storing data optimally. SQL is great at extracting table and derived/calculated data. Try this:

```
select `first`, `last`,
  (select count(*)-1 from test where `first` = t.`first`) as samef,
  (select count(*)-1 from test where `last` = t.`last`) as samef
from test t;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c673f/1

Result:

```
| first |  last | samef | samef |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|  john | smith |     1 |     2 |
|  john | adams |     1 |     1 |
|  mary |  kate |     0 |     0 |
|  kate | adams |     2 |     1 |
|  kate | smith |     2 |     2 |
|  kate | smith |     2 |     2 |
| alice | mirth |     0 |     0 |
```